# Loading facebook popout chat in iframe.. Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension

i have been attempting to load the facebook chat into a frame on the side of my normal facebook page in order to make it easier for myself to contact my friends, i have tried different methods with jquery etc, such as ajaxing the content and loading it into divs etc, however for some reason the friends list wont load like it does on the popout chat itself. here is my code, maybe someone can help:

main.js

```
 $(window).load(function() {
  $('body').append('<iframe id="heyhey" src="presence/popout.php?lite=true"></iframe>');

  $.ajax({
  url: "/presence/popout.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
  $('#heyhey').contents().find('html').html(html);
  }
});

});
```

main.css

```
#heyhey{ position:absolute;top:20px;left:1px;height:100%;width:222px;}
```

and my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "facebookchat sample",
  "description": "testing out fb chat",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.facebook.com/*"],
      "css": ["main.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.6.2.min.js", "main.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically a the moment i get a chat frame on the left, however no friends load on it, thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0):

What url are you trying to access in the `/presence/popout.php` url?
I cannot find it on Facebook.
Of course you'll create the iframe, but requesting ajax inside the content script is not allowed, you may connect to your background page (create on if you didn't) and make your ajax request throw it.

You may check my extension using content script here on google code.
http://translator-chome-extension.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Also you may check this one for facebook chat too.
http://code.google.com/p/fb-chat-client-ext/